# How to insert default value in database table when user account is created in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I am using postgre database have 10 channel in my database. This is my models with channelId and userId as foreign key:

```
class Count(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(News_Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.channelId.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
```

I want when a user account is created then 3 row inserted in the table for all 3 channelId and rate value set to 0.
suppsose a user sign up and get userIid 99 then 3 rows inserted in the table as

```
userId channelId rate
99         1      0
99         2      0
99         3      0
```

What could be the possible solution.

Comment: can you please share you view and serializer?

Comment: Hey @Annabelle please find view and serializer in following github urls https://github.com/imsaiful/backendAPI/tree/master/feed/api

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. You can use signals. Create a post_save signal for your AUTH_USER_MODEL. It is usually used to execute some logic just after a model’s save() method is called. In that signal function write logic for creating Count for all channels and rate. You can get id for ATUTH_USER_MODEL from post_signal.

   Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/
2. Create a logic for registering user for your AUTH_USER_MODEL and after user creation, create Count for all channels and rate.

Comment: I did but process is very slow.

Comment: You could make Count creation as async task so that HTTP request doesn't have to wait to complete it.