# How to insert data in for foreign key attribute from django views?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-orm

This is my model with two foreign key attribute:

```
class Count(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(News_Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.channelId.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
```

I want to insert some data when user in login , so i write following code in my views.py file

```
    for i in range(1,10):
        obj = Count.objects.filter(userId=request.user.id, channelId=cid)
        if not obj:
            o = Count.objects.create(id=Count.objects.all().count() + 1,userId=request.user.id, channelId=i,rate=0)
            o.save()
        i += 1
```

I have channel id from 1 to 10 in my db but I am getting following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Count.channelId" must be a "News_Channel" instance.
```

Kindly help to insert data.

Comment: You don't need all that nonsense to set the new ID. The database will do it for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Could you please tell what nonsense thing should I remove to perform my operation. I got one from but still getting the same error. You also helped me in the past.

Comment: this is the nonsense Daniel refers to `id=Count.objects.all().count() + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to insert an integer for a ForeignKey and you need the object

```
for i in range(1,10):
        obj = Count.objects.filter(userId=request.user.id, channelId=cid)
        if not obj:
            news_obj = News_Channel.objects.get(id=i)
            o = Count.objects.create(id=Count.objects.all().count() + 1,userId=request.user.id, channelId=news_obj,rate=0)
            o.save()
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Helped now. Earlier it was due to request.user.id

Comment: Sir  HenryM could you please guide me about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303797/how-to-insert-default-value-in-database-table-when-user-account-is-crrated-in-dj

Comment: what's the question

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303797/how-to-insert-default-value-in-database-table-when-user-account-is-created-in-dj

Comment: I mean, what don't you understand